# Convert implicitly typed object to querystring

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-4.0

In ASP.NET MVC3, some function, like HtmlHelper.ActionLink, can take in an implicitly typed object and convert it into an querystring

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link", "Action", new { id = 1, params="asd"})
```

Will result in an url like `http://www.localhost.com/controller/Action?id=1&params=asd`

Is there a built-in method to convert the properties of an object to a querystring format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

and a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            Prop1 = "foo",
            Prop2 = "bar"
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

you could use the [following overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493066.aspx) in your view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.ActionLink("Link", "Action", new RouteValueDictionary(Model))
```

in your view.